# NPm install and git push origin master is not working

Tags: git, github, npm-install

npm install jquery is not working

Please Find Screenshot Below :

[image: npm install jquery is not working]

After it, git push origin master is not working

[image: git push origin master is not working]

Comment: I have attached images for both

Comment: use sudo for npm install

Comment: I did that but nothing works

Comment: already did this too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

Github seems only supports ssh way to read&write the repo, although https way also displayed 'Read&Write'.

So you need to change your repo config on your PC to ssh way:

1. edit `.git/config` file under your repo directory
2. find `url=`entry under section `[remote "origin"]`
3. change it from `url=https://MichaelDrogalis@github.com/derekerdmann/lunch_call.git` to    `url=ssh://git@github.com/derekerdmann/lunch_call.git`. that is, change all the texts before `@` symbol to `ssh://git`
4. Save `config` file and quit. now you could use `git push origin master` to sync your repo on GitHub

Comment: @Skumar, It should be working, It looks like your user rights are broken. Try to login using Root user and try same step. Also now you can show your machine to some Linux Administrator, He/She may help you further.